# Edit and trash button shows a glimpse during the sign-out state page refreshment in MEAN JS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meanjs, ngcloak

The bootstrap edit and trash button shows a glimpse during the sign-out state page refreshment in my MEAN JS project how to fix it? I have tried with ng-clock but could not fix it.

[image]

Comment: can you provide image of that glimpse ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment brother. It is hard to take screenshot of the glimpse of the button but I will try. Anyhow, did you get an idea about the problem?

Comment: Hello Brother I have added a gif file. Please checkout the link. Thank You.